# Performance of fabric.js with many items

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, fabricjs

I'm playing around with fabric.js and wonder how to tweak performance on handling object events when having a lot of items (more than 1500...).

I have build a little example:
https://codepen.io/skurrilewelt/pen/XWWvBoP

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        var width = 10;
        var height = 10;
        var dist = 5;

        function add(left, top) {
            canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
                left: left,
                top: top,
                width: width,
                height: height,
                fill: 'green',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                padding: 10,
                draggable: false,
                hasControls: false,
                hasBorders: false,
            }));
        }

        var col = 0;
        var row = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < 50; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < 30; col++) {
                add(row * (width + dist), col * (height + dist));
            }
        }

        canvas.renderOnAddRemove = false;
        canvas.on({
            'mouse:down': function (e) {
                if (e.target) {
                    console.log(e.target);
                    canvas.getActiveObject().set("fill", '#f00');
                    canvas.renderAll();
                }
            }
        });

        canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

If you click an rect you will have to wait approximatly 3 secs until the rect will change it's color.

Are there other approaches or can I enhance the performance of this? I will need up to 3500 objects...
Thanks in advance

Comment: When i try your codepen, color change is instantaneous...

Comment: Can you confirm the same with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcjwsuLv/)?

Comment: Yes, the color change occurs very quickly with this fiddle too...

Comment: Okay, you were all right. It must have been a browser problem that persisted until I rebooted the computer. Sorry for inconvenience. But I tried to accomplish this with div containers and jquery and it turns out, that that solution is much faster. For comparision: https://codepen.io/skurrilewelt/pen/dyyxaVJ